# One Liner Destructor?

Tags: c++, nodes, destructor

how can I write a one liner destructor for a Node class? I assumed something like,

```
~Node() {delete Node; };
```

would have worked as a public function for my node class, but it's not the case. As a frame of reference, my objects are structured like this:

```
    template <class T>
    struct List{
        public:
              class Node{
                   public:
                        T* data;
                        Node* next;
                        //node attributes, and a destructor as below
                        ~Node() {delete Node; };
              }
        private:
              //private elements
        }
     }
```

Comment: Are you sure you need one? It's possible that the compiler-generated destructor will work fine for you. If you did not allocate anything that specifically needs deleting, you can just say `~Node() {}` in which case it is trivial and you can let the compiler do it for you.

Comment: @Cyber: But that wouldn't be a trivial dtor... better use `= default;` or the implicit one.

Comment: @Deduplicator That was a poor choice of words, I meant trivial in the layman's sense of the term meaning it didn't do anything significant. I should have used another word since a "(non)trivial destructor" already has a defined technical meaning.

Comment: `delete Node`? `Node` is a class name, so this wouldn't compile.

Comment: sorry, that was probably relevant since it is a templated class structure containing a templated node. I do not believe the compiler-generated destructor is working, as I still have blocks of memory unfreed from the nodes I created in my test file (the nodes within the lists are freed by the list destructor).

Comment: Consider using `std::unique_ptr`. No overhead, but simplifies memory-management much.

Comment: ah, that's why it doesn't compile then. how do I tell it to delete the node then in a more effective way?

Comment: use smart pointer so you don't need destructor

Comment: not allowed to :/ we must keep the elements of std that we use to a minimum (unique_ptr is not one of the basics we are allowed to use)

Comment: Is the destructor limited to one line?  If so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to decide whether or not you really need a destructor: you need one only when the default destructor that compiler provides does not fit your needs. Generally, you end up writing a destructor when objects of your class hold "plain" pointers to other objects that they "own", which is not the case in the code in your post.

Once you decide that you do need a destructor, you need to see what it needs to clean up. In a linked list situation, you may need to clean up the chain of nodes that follow the current node. You can potentially do it in a single line of code, like this:

```
~Node() { delete next; } // No semicolon is necessary here
```

However, this is not a good choice, because a deletion of `Node *next` will trigger a recursive chain of deletions, which may overflow the stack. You would be better off following the chain of nodes with a `while` loop, deleting the nodes as you go. You have to be careful to set `next` to `nullptr` before deleting the node in order to avoid double deletions:

```
~Node() {
    Node *curr = next;
    while (curr) {
        Node *tmp = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
        tmp->next = nullptr;
        delete tmp;
    }
    next = nullptr;
}
```

Note that using a smart pointer would work too. However, in this situation you would be running a risk of overflowing the stack when the list is too long, because the deletions would happen recursively.

Answer (score 1):

*Destructors with content are generally only needed when the class allocates memory or when you want to take some explicit action upon the destruction. And delete should indicate the instance of the object you want destroyed.

For example, if you had a series of linked Nodes and you wanted to delete all subsequent Nodes when calling delete on one, your code may look like:

```
class Node {
 Node();
 ~Node();
 void link(Node * n);
private:
  Node * next;
}
Node::Node() {
 next = 0;
}
Node::~Node() {
 delete next;
}
Node::link(Node *n) {
 next = n;
}
```

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Didn't you mean the `Node` containing a `Node`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Correct, I have corrected the code above

Answer (score 0):

First, a bit of advice:

Use smart-pointers whenever possible, and save yourself lots of headaches.
`std::unique_ptr` does not have any overhead.

Next, consider making `Node` a plain data-structure, without any curlicues.
`List` is a far better place to do the heavy-lifting.

That also allows you to avoid recursion on deletion, instead using far saner iteration.

```
template <class T> struct List{
    struct Node{
        std::unique_ptr<T> data;
        Node* next;
    }
    ~List() {
        Node* p = head;
        while(p) {
            Node* tmp = p->next;
            delete p;
            p = tmp;
        }
    }
    private:
          //private elements
    }
 }
```

Also, consider whether you really want to have pointers to the payload, instead of the payload itself in the `Node`.